# Embedding YTPlayerView In UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiwebview, youtube-api

I'm creating a UIScrollView that can hold images and videos from different sources. I first created and added a UIView for each image/video to the UIScrollView, then add the image/video view/layer. This works fine for images and videos using AVFoundation; however, does not work for videos using the [Youtube API](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper).

Here's my code for adding the YTPlayerView to the UIView within the UIScrollView:

```
YTPlayerView * youtubePlayerView = [[YTPlayerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollViewWidth, self.scrollViewHeight)];
youtubePlayerView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollViewWidth, self.scrollViewHeight);

NSString * youtubePath = [media getMediaPath]; //Valid Youtube URL as NSString

NSMutableString *videoUrlCopy = [NSMutableString stringWithString:youtubePath];

NSString *vID =  [videoUrlCopy lastPathComponent];

NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                            @"playsinline" : @1
                            };

youtubePlayerView.delegate = self;

[contentView addSubview:youtubePlayerView]; //ContentView is subview of UIScrollview

[youtubePlayerView loadWithVideoId:vID playerVars:playerVars];
[youtubePlayerView playVideo];
```

When I try to load the youtube video with loadWithVideoId, the process terminates within YTPlayerView here: `UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];` throwing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

```
- (UIWebView *)createNewWebView {
  UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
  webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
  webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
  webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
  return webView;
}
```

Interestingly, I've gotten the Youtube videos to show adding the YTPlayerView directly as a subview to `self.view`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, using

```
pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', :git=>'https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper', :commit=>'head'
```

instead of using `pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper'`

Cheers